# Allowing users to script in-game?

Tags: java, scripting, lua

So part of the game I am making includes letting the players use a simple scripting language. I was busy creating my own, but after playing Feed the Beast one time (XD) I saw a Minecraft mod called Computer Craft. With Computer Craft, players can write Lua that is executed in-game.

My question is, how would I implement Lua into my game? I know LuaJava exists for executing Lua files in Java and vice-versa, but I do not understand how that would work. Somewhere online, I saw someone mention that you need to create a virtual machine, but how do I do that in Java?

Thanks all!